# How to load 60,000 data points without datagrouping in highstock chart?

Tags: highcharts

Am using high stock chart (timeline chart) and load  60,000 data points without data Grouping the width and height of the chart is 800 & 400.
is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can disable http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.enabled, modify turbothreshold parameter http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.turboThreshold

Please take look at the article http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/48-loading-millions-of-points-in-highcharts

Comment: Thanks .. if i disable dataGrouping all Major browser are hanging.

Comment: You can disable animations / shadows

Comment: But am using only tool tip there is no animation at all.